# Meaning of $(\textbf{x}_i,\epsilon_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$ is a sequence of independent observations

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, independence, economics

In William Greene's Econometric Analysis book (7th edition), page 64 states (right above equation 4-20) assumption A5a:
$$\tag{A5a}
(\textbf{x}_i,\epsilon_i)\quad i=1,\dots,n \quad \text{ is a sequence of independent observations}
$$
(note that $x_i$ is a vector of either stochastic or non-stochastic objects)

**My question is the following:** What exactly does this mean (both intuitively and in mathematical terms)

My understanding is that this means (in intuition)

- each $\textbf{x}_i$ needs to be independent of $\textbf{x_j}$ (i.e. $P(\textbf{x}_i \cap \textbf{x}_j) = P(\textbf{x}_i)P(\textbf{x}_j)$
- each $\epsilon_i$ must be independent of each $\epsilon_j$

In terms of of math, if $f_i$ denotes the joint distribution of $(\textbf{x}_i,\epsilon_i)$, and $f$ denotes the joint distribution of all the pairs, then I think it requires
$$
f((\textbf{x}_1,\epsilon_1),\dots,(\textbf{x}_n,\epsilon_n)) = \Pi f_i(\textbf{x}_1,\epsilon_1)\dots f_n(\textbf{x}_n,\epsilon_n)
$$

This condition does not require anything about how $\textbf{x}_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ relate, though, does it?

---

Edit: Note, I am only asking about what assumption A5a implies(/requires), **not** about what might be needed for least squares or some other estimation technique (which likely requires additional assumptions)

Comment: I believe that the $\epsilon_i$ should be independent of the $\mathbf{x}_i$.

Comment: @rubikscube09 I believe that is a separate assumption, yes, but I don't think it is required for $(\textbf{x}_i,\epsilon_i)$ and $(\textbf{x}_j,\epsilon_j$ to be independent?(I could be wrong though, hence this question)

Comment: From A5a you cannot deduce that each $ϵ_i$ must be independent of each $ϵ_j$

Comment: *This condition does not require anything about how $x_i$ and $ϵ_i$ relate, though, does it?* I agree to you.

Comment: @callculus *From A5a you cannot deduce that each $\epsilon_i$
 must be independent of each $\epsilon_j$.* So then $(\textbf{x}_i,\epsilon_i)$ can be independent of $(\textbf{x}_j,\epsilon_j)$, but $\epsilon_i$ and $\epsilon_j$ are dependent? (and the similar would be true for $\textbf{x_i}$ and $\textbf{x}_j$ too can be dependent?)

Comment: Are there made any other assumptions ? From A5a alone it is hard to make any conclustions.

Comment: @callculus I just want to know what conclusions can be made from A5a alone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the random variables are absolutely continuous, your characterization that the joint density is the product of the marginals, i.e.

$$f(x_1,\epsilon_1,...,x_n,\epsilon_n)=\Pi_i f(x_i,\epsilon_i)$$

is correct.

Note that random vectors $X,Y$ being independent implies $g(X),h(Y)$ are also independent for measurable real-valued functions $g,h$. Applying functions that marginalize out each component in your setup, it follows that $x_i$ is independent of $x_j$, and also $\epsilon_i$ is independent of $\epsilon_j$ for $j\neq i$.